# Counting fields in multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have thhree tables:

*Table Subjects:*
field name: term

*Table Definitions:*
field name: what

*Table Codeblocks:*
Field name: codeblock

Wanted the number of occurences of the three fields over three tables (counting). I wrote this sql query (it works alright btw):

```
SELECT Entity, COUNT(FieldToCount) AS quantity
FROM (SELECT Entity, FieldToCount
   FROM (SELECT  'Subjects' AS Entity, COUNT(term) AS FieldToCount
       FROM          dbo.subjects
       GROUP BY term
       UNION ALL
       SELECT     'Definitions' AS Entity, COUNT(what) AS FieldToCount
       FROM         dbo.definitions
       GROUP BY what
       UNION ALL
       SELECT     'codeblocks' AS Entity, COUNT(codeblock) AS FieldToCount
       FROM         dbo.codeblocks
       GROUP BY codeblock) AS SUMTABLE) AS REPORT
GROUP BY Entity, FieldToCount
```

Got this result:

```
Entity      quantity
----------- -----------
codeblocks  3
Definitions 4
Subjects    2
```

.. in other words counting the occurences of a field in each of the three tables.

Now how could this query be written more compact or elegantly?
Or the question rephrased: what is the minimal or more elegant way of counting the occurences of a field in multiple tables?

(in Transact sql)

Comment: You are overly complicating your query by having multiple sql selects. You just need inner select with unions in this case.

Comment: Great, thanks. 

So to explain the whole solution here (like tommy_o laid it out in the end):
 
The UNION operator is used to combine results of multiple select statements. Each SELECT statement must query the same number of columns. The columns queried must all have the same data types, and be in the same order in each of the queries.

Then We do three select statements; one for each table, and concatenate the results with the help of the Union All (some sort of join, isn't it?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  'Subjects' AS Entity
        , count(term) AS FieldToCount
FROM     dbo.subjects
UNION ALL
SELECT   'Definitions' AS Entity
        , count(what) AS FieldToCount
FROM        dbo.definitions
UNION ALL
SELECT  'codeblocks' AS Entity
        , count(codeblock) AS FieldToCount
FROM     dbo.codeblocks
```

I was lazy and tested this against some sys tables:

```
SELECT  'Subjects' AS Entity
        , count(name) AS FieldToCount
FROM    sys.tables
--
UNION ALL
SELECT   'Definitions' AS Entity
        , count(name) AS FieldToCount
FROM    sys.columns
--
UNION ALL
SELECT   'AnotherChoice' AS Entity
        , count(object_id) AS FieldToCount
FROM    sys.tables
```

Not sure if you have other requirements, but this seems to work.

Comment: Yes. I understand. Thank you for this explanation. it got a bit shorter this way.

Comment: Perfect. And that ended up in three lines effectively.